# RPM with RHEL: install 2 version of same package / different arch

Tags: linux, redhat, rpm, 32bit-64bit, java

I think the title is pretty self explanatory :)
Is it possible, under RHEL (v 5) to install 2 instances of the same packages with 32 bit support for one and 64 bits support for the other one?

Obviously, the running host has a 64 bit kernel and has the compatibility libraries required. (in this case, we would need a 64 bits JDK and a 32 bits one).
If yes, are there any special rpm flag to use (change of installation directory for instance)?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Just install your x86_64 and your i386/i686 packages using the `rpm` command in the same manner as usual.

There are plenty of instances of mixed-architecture packages that need to coexist. Look at glibc or from one of my other systems... Note the two entries.

```
[root@LAX ~]# rpm -qi zlib

Name        : zlib                         Relocations: (not relocatable)
Version     : 1.2.3                             Vendor: CentOS
Release     : 27.el6                        Build Date: Wed Dec  7 09:54:41 2011
Install Date: Fri Nov 30 12:50:28 2012         Build Host: c6b18n1.dev.centos.org
Group       : System Environment/Libraries   Source RPM: zlib-1.2.3-27.el6.src.rpm
Size        : 152225                           License: zlib and Boost
Signature   : RSA/SHA1, Thu Dec  8 13:48:00 2011, Key ID 0946fca2c105b9de
Packager    : CentOS BuildSystem <http://bugs.centos.org>
URL         : http://www.gzip.org/zlib/
Summary     : The zlib compression and decompression library
Description :
Zlib is a general-purpose, patent-free, lossless data compression
library which is used by many different programs.

Name        : zlib                         Relocations: (not relocatable)
Version     : 1.2.3                             Vendor: CentOS
Release     : 27.el6                        Build Date: Wed Dec  7 09:51:15 2011
Install Date: Fri Nov 30 13:58:46 2012         Build Host: c6b18n1.dev.centos.org
Group       : System Environment/Libraries   Source RPM: zlib-1.2.3-27.el6.src.rpm
Size        : 139037                           License: zlib and Boost
Signature   : RSA/SHA1, Thu Dec  8 13:47:42 2011, Key ID 0946fca2c105b9de
Packager    : CentOS BuildSystem <http://bugs.centos.org>
URL         : http://www.gzip.org/zlib/
Summary     : The zlib compression and decompression library
Description :
Zlib is a general-purpose, patent-free, lossless data compression
library which is used by many different programs.
```

Answer (score 0):

As said, you can use `rpm` command in the traditional way to get the work done. If you are installing by `yum` it would be a little different. Either you have to specify the 32 bit architecture package specifically like `yum install <32_bit_package>`.

Or you can edit the `/etc/yum.conf' file and put the line

```
multilib_policy=all
```

And it should be done. In numerous instances, I had to install 32 bit and 64 bit glibc or gcc packages and it works.